# How to pass data through route and assign to text box in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to pass data through route then assign to the text box for edit in `modal` popup.

My controller code is:

```
public function edit($id) {
    $abc = property_type::find($id);
    return redirect('/admin/property-type')->with('popup','open');
}
```

Popup is to open modal popup. `$abc` has three values:  ID, name and description. I want to assign description and name with two different text box:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Session::get('abc')}}" name="update_prop_name" >
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Session::get('abc')}}" name="update_prop_desc" >
```

Comment: Can you share why you are using redirect `admin/property-type` ?

Comment: can you share the route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anywhere where you're setting `abc` into session, so `value="{{ Session::get("abc") }}` will be `null`.

Add this to your `edit` function:

```
public function edit($id){
  $abc = property_type::find($id);
  session()->put("abc", $abc);
  return redirect("/admin/property-type")->with(["popup" => "popup"]);
}
```

Also, using `session()->get("abc")` will return the whole object, and not a specific property. Might want to adjust to:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ session::get("abc") ? session()->get("abc")->name : "" }}" name="update_prop_name" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ session::get("abc") ? session()->get("abc")->description : "" }}" name="update_prop_desc" />
```

Note: the ternary `?` operator will also handle `session()->get("abc")` returning `null`

Comment: Are you sure that `>with(["popup" => "popup"]);` will work with `redirect` ?

Comment: You could use `session()->has('abc')` since it returns a boolean.

Comment: @C2486 Quite sure yes; Your edit suggests using `return view()` instead of `return redirect()`, but that can get problematic with `POST` requests, since refreshing the view will submit the `POST` again (as an example)

Comment: @C2486 `redirect()` + `with()` -> puts it in the session, `view()` + `with()` -> puts it in the view.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Correct, but only for 1 request (essentially `flash`), so setting via `session()->put()` may or may not be the right approach here. And yes, `session()->has()` makes more sense, but `session()->get()` will return `null` or something, which satisfies that check also.

Comment: @TimLewis You are right! Probably it'd be better to use `withInput()` + custom array and then `old('abc', DEFAULT_VALUE)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use session instead

```
 public function edit($id)
 {
        $abc=property_type::find($id);
        session("abc",$abc);
        session("popup","open");
        return redirect('/admin/property-type');
 }
```

And get session  value

```
  $abc = session("abc");
```